# Cross compile C++ application for ARM64 with openSSL libraries

Tags: c++, openssl, cross-compilation, arm64

I made an application in C++ for x86_64 and it works fine on Ubuntu.

Now I want to run the same application on arm64 board running Ubuntu.
For this I downloaded a cross-compilation tool chain from the web-site of hardware manufacturer.
I'm compiling the source code on my host machine(x86_64) for the target machine(ARM64).

The build is done by `cmake`; but while the compilation is in progress, compilation stops with the following message:

*`fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
     #include < openssl/evp.h >
                         ^
     compilation terminated.`*

I have not done any change in code except for providing tool-chain's path for `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` in root `CMakeList.txt` file.

Please let me know what changes do I need to do to complete this compilation and test my application.

Please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: Did you take care to install OpenSSL on your computer?the missing file must be located as `/usr/lib/openssl/evp.h`

Comment: @damadam: Yes openssl has been installed. Actually the application code has been built for X86. Now I'm building the same source code for ARM. However, do you mean that I have to install openssl again in my host machine(x86) for compiling for ARM?

Comment: No, cross-compilation is just using all librairies needed from your computer, and adapt the software for the target machine (an ARM64 in your case), but your error just said that the header `evp.h` doesn't exist, so just check the folder `/usr/lib/openssl/`

Comment: Also, it's possible that your error is just a permission denied to let `cmake` accessed these librairies

Comment: @damadam: To your earlier point, evp.h exists in /usr/include/openssl but I didn't find it in /usr/lib/openssl/. Also the permission may be fine as it built successfully for x86.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the wrong path, so try to use `sudo cmake` instead of `cmake`; also, I would take a look at my previous work on that later, I could help you more

Comment: Nope! sudo cmake did not help.

Comment: I think you will need the header files for the target system where your cross compilation tool chain expects them.

Comment: @CarstenS: Yes I also think so. But but where are the headers expected? How do I give path to the tool-chain to look for headers? Hunting for these answers..
Thank you for the guidence, BTW.. :)